# Ignore function on if condition PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code but I want it to ignore 'customer::$data['vehicle_id']' when category_id = 1, 4, 9.

I've struggled with the code below and to add another function is out of my capabilities, so any advice would be great. Thanks in advance.

If vehicle_id is not selected it works fine.

```
if (empty($_GET['manufacturer_id'])) {
  $manufacturers_query = database::query(
    "select distinct m.id, m.name from ". DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS ." p
    left join ". DB_TABLE_MANUFACTURERS ." m on m.id = p.manufacturer_id ".
    (!empty($_GET['category_id']) ? " left join " . DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " pc on pc.product_id = p.id " : "").
    (!empty(customer::$data['vehicle_id']) ? " left join " . DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_VEHICLES . " ptv on ptv.product_id = p.id " : "").
    "where p.status
    and manufacturer_id
    ". (!empty($_GET['category_id']) ? "and pc.category_id = " . (int)$_GET['category_id']  : "") ."
    ". (!empty(customer::$data['vehicle_id']) ? "and ptv.vehicle_id = " . (int)customer::$data['vehicle_id']  : "") ."
    order by m.name asc;"
  );
```

I've tried using this:

```
". (!empty(customer::$data['vehicle_id']) && (!empty($_GET['category_id']) || !array_intersect(array(1, 4, 9), $_GET['category_id'])) ? "and ptv.vehicle_id = " . (int)customer::$data['vehicle_id']  : "") ."
```

EDIT:

```
while($manufacturer = database::fetch($manufacturers_query)) {
      $box_filter->snippets['manufacturers'][] = array(
        'id' => $manufacturer['id'],
        'name' => $manufacturer['name'],
        'href' => document::ilink('manufacturer', array('manufacturer_id' => $manufacturer['id'])),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Find yourself a nice query builder

Comment: Query is vuln to mysql injection aswell.

Comment: You should look into prepared statements with parameters, and remove the logic from your SQL. Saves you from SQL injection, and is a lot more readable. If you need to build the query in chunks to decide if you need to include a column or a field, do it in a more structured way, one string at a time.

Comment: So you want to restrict by vehicle_id when vehicle_id is not empty _and_ category_id is not in the array of (1, 4, 9), right?  That should give you a pretty good hint of what to do.

Comment: Not sure how to explain it better but it works when vehicle_id is not selected. And when vehicle_id is selected I want it to be ignored in in the array of category_id of (1,4,9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your rather messy code and refactored it so it is readable, maintainable and better in a lot of small and big ways. It's by no means perfect, but now it can be reasoned about.

I also eliminated the SQL Injection opportunities for you, but you still need to redesign your `database::query()` function so it accepts an array of parameters to be used with your sql query in a prepared statement execution. I used named placeholders in your query to make it readable.

Doing the refactor this way, allowed me to add a boolean flag I can set if your ignore condition is true (`$_GET['category_id']` equals one of `[1,4,9]`)

```
if (empty($_GET['manufacturer_id'])) 
{
    $ignoreVehicleId = false;
    $params = [];
    $query = "select distinct m.id, m.name 
                from ${DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS} p
                left join ${DB_TABLE_MANUFACTURERS} m on m.id = p.manufacturer_id ";

    if( !empty($_GET['category_id'])
    {
        $query .= " left join ${DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES} pc on pc.product_id = p.id ";

        if(in_array($_GET["category_id"], [1,4,9])   // <---  This array should be better documented to not use MAGIC NUMBERS. What is 1,4 or 9?
        {
            $ignoreVehicleId = true;
        }
    }

    if( $ignoreVehicleId === false && !empty( customer::$data['vehicle_id'])
    {
        $query .= " left join ${DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_VEHICLES} ptv on ptv.product_id = p.id ";
    }

    $query .= "where p.status and manufacturer_id ";

    /*
    *   In the following two IF's named parameters for prepared statements are being used.
    *   You need to refactor the database::query() function to accept a params array.
    *   Read up on using prepared statements with mysqli_* or better, PDO. 
    *
    *   DO NOT BUILD QUERIES WITH VARIABLES ANY OTHER WAY!!! 
    *
    *   If you do you are asking to be pwned by someone using your less than secure
    *   practises to do SQL Injection.
    */
    if( !empty($_GET['category_id'])
    {
        " and pc.category_id = :category_id ";
        $params[":category_id"] = (int)$_GET['category_id'];
    }

    if( $ignoreVehicleId === false && !empty(customer::$data['vehicle_id'])
    {
        " and ptv.vehicle_id = :vehicle_id ";
        $params[":vehicle_id"] = (int)customer::$data['vehicle_id'];
    }

    $query .= " order by m.name asc;"

    $manufacturers_query = database::query($query, $params);

}
```

Comment: Thats great, but I have some issue with the original code. I've added another line of code in the first post. It doesn't work together now. Please check the code after EDIT: Thnks.

Comment: @JoeDoe Did you update database::query to actually accept the parameters and use prepared statements? If not, then the query will be erroneous.

Comment: @JoeDoe where is `database` defined? Is it your own class? Or did you set up a constant to hold the database object?

Comment: No, it's not my own class. It's defined by CMS. Looking into it.

Comment: @JoeDoe You have not mentioned you are using a CMS. Perhaps it already has support for this?

Comment: No, I've contacted with the developer and he confirmed that this needs a custom fuction.

Comment: @JoeDoe I would recommend the CMS developer to start using prepared statements as the default as well... It's really the only way to be sure you're not injected with sql.